# Changing PFObject ACL Permission With Read Only Access

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I've been struggling with a problem with Parse Objects for a while and I'm not sure what the best implementation is.

I have a PFObject that is created by another user, a message, and this user has given me Read access so I can read this message. I do not want to see this message any more but I don't want to delete it because it's not my message.

If I adjust the ACL permission to remove my Read access

```
object.ACL setReadAccess:NO forUser:[PFUser currentUser]];
```

And then go to save the object

```
object saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)
```

I receive the error

```
Error: object not found for update (Code: 101, Version: 1.2.15)
```

This is obviously because I only have read access and not write access to update the object.

I was thinking possibly having a block message object for each user but this feels a bit messy.

Can anyone think of a better implementation for my issue?

All ideas are great, just want to bounce ideas off fellow iOS programmers.

Comment: Does anyone have any sound logic that could help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up working it out by creating cloud code that I call to remove a user from a Message. Using the Parse.Cloud.UseMasterKey() you can do anything you want without permissions.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("RemoveUserFromMessage", function(request, response) {
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey(); 

var query = new Parse.Query("Notes");
query.get(request.params.noteId, {
        success: function(note) {
        var noteACL = note.getACL();
        noteACL.setReadAccess(request.params.userId, false);
        noteACL.setWriteAccess(request.params.userId, false);
        note.setACL(noteACL);
        note.save();

        response.success();
    },
    error: function() {
        response.error("can’t find note");
    }
}); 
});
```